# An FAILED CONFIGURATION error being thrown out when run automation test cases via batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, automation, testng

Much appreciated if anyone can help out this error. I am trying to run the testng.xml via batch file for some automation test cases, however I am getting a FAILDED CONFIGURATION error message as below, any advises?

Thanks

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator
        at testCases.TestBase.setUp(TestBase.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocat
ionHelper.java:85)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:51
0)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMet
hodWorker.java:170)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
        at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1355)
        at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1324)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurat
or
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 24 more

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod beforeMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDown
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod beforeMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod beforeMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDown
SKIPPED: testCreateCase
SKIPPED: testGoToCaseHomePage
java.lang.Throwable: Method UI_CaseHomePage.testGoToCaseHomePage()[pri:0, instan
ce:testCases.UI_WebElements.UI_CaseHomePage@18ef96] depends on not successfully
finished methods
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1033)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWork
er.java:125)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
```

Answer (score 1):

log4j or its appropriate version is missing in your classpath. Just add it in and it should work then.